# Buscador palabras en un String con JavaScript metodo search()

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy creando un buscador de palabras con JavaScript, el código que tengo es este:

```js
function test(){
    
     let txt= document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML;
     let dato= document.getElementById("in").value;
     //Convirtiendo a minuscula
     txt= txt.toLowerCase();
     dato= dato.toLowerCase();
    
     let b= txt.search(dato);
          
          if(b === -1){
          console.log(false);
          }else{
          console.log(true);
          }

}
```

```html
<p id="txt">Tv marca Importante pantalla LED es el producto indicado para usted con 40 pulgadas de Tamaño</p>

<input id="in" type="text">

<button onclick="test()">Buscar</button>
```

El problema es el siguiente, distingue mayúsculas y no quiero que pase eso. Ejemplo si busco  `tv` retorna **false**, pero si busco `Tv` retorna **true**; El funcionamiento correcto debería ser que en ambos casos retorne **true**. Además, debería retorna true si un grupo de palabras están en el párrafo por ejemplo: si busco `tv led 40`, la respuesta debería ser **true**, por que las tres palabras se encuentran en el párrafo. Estaré muy agradecido por sus aportes, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Las palabras reservadas `var`, `let` y `const` significan algo para ti? Existen para la declaración de variables, intenta usarlas. Por otro lado, ¿debes usar `search()` o puedes usar cualquier otro método?

Comment: Hola Mauricio, puedo usar otro método para realizar esta tarea.

Comment: Una solución rápida para lo que ya tienes, es agregar un `.toLowerCase()` a ambos strings para evitar problemas de *case sensitive*.

Comment: Gracias Ricardo, tienes razón `toLowerCase()` elimina el problema de mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: Añadí al código de ejemplo `toLowerCase()` para solucionar el problema de distinción de mayúsculas

Comment: Puedes revisar la edición a mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uno de los problemas en tu implementación es que no estás tomando en cuenta el caso en que el campo de tipo `input` está vacío. Cuando esto sucede su valor (`value`) es el de una cadena vacía.

Una cadena vacía es como el conjunto vacío en los conjuntos numéricos: siempre está contenido en cualquier cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let cadena = "Hola";
console.log(`¿La cadena "${cadena}" incluye un caracter vacío? ${cadena.includes("")}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Debido a esto tu función falla para este caso particular, a menos que se deba devolver `true` cuando la cadena a buscar es el carácter vacío.

Una solución usando [`search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) o usando [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) podría ser la siguiente:

```js
function buscarConSearch(event) {
  const texto = document.getElementById('texto').innerText.toLowerCase();
  const patron = document.getElementById('patron').value.toLowerCase().trim();
  if(!patron) {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = '';
    return;
  }
  let index = texto.search(patron);
  if(index < 0) {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = `La cadena "${patron}" no se ha encontrado.`;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = `La cadena "${patron}" ha sido encontrada en la posición: ${index}.`;
  }
}

function buscarConIncludes(event) {
  const texto = document.getElementById('texto').innerText.toLowerCase();
  const patron = document.getElementById('patron').value.toLowerCase();
  if(!patron) {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = '';
    return;
  }
  if(texto.includes(patron)) {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = `La cadena "${patron}" ha sido encontrada.`;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = `La cadena "${patron}" no se ha encontrado.`;
  }
}

document.getElementById('buscarSearch').addEventListener('click', buscarConSearch);

document.getElementById('buscarIncludes').addEventListener('click', buscarConIncludes);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 60%;
}
.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: .3rem;
  padding: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text" id="texto">TV de su marca favorita, LED, 54 pulgadas, UHD</div>
  <div class="text">
    <label for="patron">Texto a buscar (case insensitive):</label>
    <input id="patron" placeholder="Escriba aquí" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <button id="buscarSearch">Buscar con SEARCH</button>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <button id="buscarIncludes">Buscar con INCLUDES</button>
  </div>
  <div id="resultado" class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Como se observa en el código, básicamente hago un `return` temprano de la función en caso de que el texto a buscar sea una cadena vacía:

```
if(!patron) { ... }  // se lee como: si no hay patron
```

Una cadena vacía, el número 0, `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `NaN` son valores considerados [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), es decir, retornan `false` cuando son evaluados en un contexto booleano. Es por ello que pruebo si el valor de `patron` retorna `false` al evaluarlo en el contexto booleano de la sentencia `if`.

El método `includes()` devuelve directamente `true` si el patron está incluido en el texto y `false` en caso contrario.

La diferencia es que `search()` te devuelve el índice posicional (empezando en cero (0) desde la izquierda de la cadena) donde inicia la subcadena o patrón a buscar, esto te da un poco más de información que un simple `true` o `false`, ya que te dice que el patrón fue encontrado y en qué posición se encuentra.

**Nota:**

`search()` te devolverá la posición del primer elemento que encuentre dentro de la cadena.

**EDICIÓN**

Gracias a tu oportuno [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/474956/buscador-palabras-en-un-string-con-javascript-metodo-search/474990?noredirect=1#comment845282_474990), haré la modificación al método para que retorne lo que deseas en realidad.

Necesitas buscar una serie de palabras dentro de la cadena, sin importar el orden, para ello puedes apoyarte del método [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para separar el valor del `input` en sus palabras componentes. Luego puedes recorrer el `array` resultante y devolver `true` si todas las palabras del `array` se encuentran en la cadena o `false` en caso contrario.

Esto devolvería `false` si una palabra falla la prueba, puedes ajustar esto de acuerdo a tu caso de uso.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// función que devuelve true si todas las palabras están incluidas en el texto
function allWordsIncluded(words, text) {
  if(!words.length) return false;
  for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if(!text.includes(words[i])) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function buscarConIncludes(event) {
  const texto = document.getElementById('texto').innerText.toLowerCase();
  // obtenemos el patron de busqueda, se usa trim()
  const patron = document.getElementById('patron').value.toLowerCase().trim();
  if(!patron) {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = '';
    return;
  }
  let encontrado = allWordsIncluded(patron.split(' '), texto);
  if(encontrado) {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = `Todas las palabras: "${patron.split(' ').join(', ')}" han sido encontradas.`;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = `No todas las palabras fueron encontradas`;
  }
}

document.getElementById('buscarIncludes').addEventListener('click', buscarConIncludes);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 60%;
}
.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: .3rem;
  padding: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text" id="texto">TV de su marca favorita, LED, 54 pulgadas, UHD</div>
  <div class="text">
    <label for="patron">Texto a buscar (case insensitive):</label>
    <input id="patron" placeholder="Escriba aquí" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <button id="buscarIncludes">Buscar con INCLUDES</button>
  </div>
  <div id="resultado" class="text"></div>
</div>
```

En el código anterior he escrito una función que devuelve `true` si todas la palabras están dentro del texto. Ya podrías ajustar esto a tu caso de uso, por ejemplo devolver `true` si la mayoría de palabras están en el texto, o si al menos 1 palabra tiene coincidencia, esto queda a tu criterio y necesidad.

Comment: Mauricio gracias por tu buena explicación, pero el problema expuesto en esta pregunta aun persiste en tu código. SI busco `led` me retorna la posición, eso esta bien. Y si, siempre que busco una palabra funciona excelente, el problema se presenta al buscar una serie de palabras. Ejemplo, si busco `tv led` retorna como no encontrado, pero las palabras `tv led` se encuentran en el párrafo. Ósea si busco `tv led` o `led tv` debería retornar una respuesta de que esas palabras se encuentran en el párrafo o bien un true. .

Comment: haz probado con poner `uhd           `, es algo raro el resultado, creo que un pequeño `if` para no mostrar nada en caso sea vacío lo resolvería

Comment: Muchas gracias, Mauricio el código funciona excelente.

Comment: Hola @Christian gracias por tu comentario. no noto nada raro al ingresar `uhd`

Comment: @Usiel si tu buscas `uhd           ` el resultado es `"uhd, , , , , , , , , , , "` (con espacios de más)

Comment: Tienes razón @Christian, pero como me comentas con un `if` se puede solucionar

Comment: @Christian pocos escribirán lo que sugieres, pero tienes razón. En ese caso, se puede sanitizar la entrada con [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), que elimina los espacios anteriores y posteriores que estén demás en el patrón de búsqueda. De todas formas, ya está editado. Saludos